# Regex: How Do You Match All Text Not Within [] But Only On Lines That Start With a Sequence?

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting

I'm making a custom Syntax Highlighter for Sublime for Macros for a [Script on Roll20: Scriptcards](https://wiki.roll20.net/Script:ScriptCards) and I'm making some progress on getting the regular expressions I need for it to work, but I have a snag:

I can't seem to get an expression that matches all of the output text on an output line.

In Scriptcards, having a line start with `--+TEXT|` will generate an output with whatever is after that sequence. So, a full line might look like this:

```
--+Move|Go [$Num] spaces [&Direction]
```

Which would output a line with header `Move` and display `Go X spaces (up/down/left/right)` as `[$Num]` and `[&Direction]` represent numeric and string variables, respectively.

What I want to color the same is `Move`, `Go_`, and `_spaces_` (where `_` denotes whitespace), although in reality, since this is an output line, there can be a lot of variation to how many variables show up and where.

So, in a nutshell, I'm trying to match all text in a line that starts with `--+TEXT|` that doesn't appear between `[]` and isn't the `--+` and `|` of the starting sequence.

Some expressions I've tried:

This one gets all of the text not within `[]`:

```
\[^\]]+(?![^\[]*\])\m
```

This one gets all of the text after the starting sequence before `[`

```
\(?<=--\+.*?\|)[^\]]+(?![^\[]*\])\m
```

This one gets the text in the starting sequence:

```
\(?<=--\+).*?(?=\|)\m
```

My problem is just joining all of these pieces together to work the way I want. I'm starting to think it's not possible with the way Regex works but I figured I'd try here and see if more experienced eyes would have any insight.

Comment: Just to confirm: do you understand that you need three separate matches, as every match has a start and end position? (In other words, you can't have a match that starts at `3`, ends at `37`, but does not include some characters in between.)

Comment: Also, which version of Sublime are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution that should work even without assumption that square brackets contain single word:

```
(?<=^--\+)\w+?(?=\|)|(?<=^--\+.+\|.*)(?<=^([^\]\[\n]*\[[^\]\[\n]*])*[^\]\[]*)[^\]\[\n]+
```

Here:

- `(?<=^--\+)\w+?(?=\|)` matches word between `--+` and `|`, in the beginning of line,
- `(?<=^--\+.+\|.*)(?<=^([^\]\[\n]*\[[^\]\[\n]*])*[^\]\[\n]*)[^\]\[\n]+` matches all word in line beginning with `--+` that are outside of square brackets:

  - `(?<=^--\+.+\|.*)` check that line in which word is matched start with `--+word|`,
  - `(?<=^([^\]\[\n]*\[[^\]\[\n]*])*[^\]\[\n]*)` checks that to the left of matched word all opening square brackets paired with closing ones. This way we can be sure our word is outside of brackets.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J1HNcW/2).

Comment: This worked splendidly! Only thing I had to do was remove the last '+', I got the error "Nothing to Repeat" on Regexr. Turns out I neglected to mention some additional considerations (like how variables can have functions or attributes, or capturing punctuation) but as far as I can tell this handles those just fine! Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: @mshaw, that second `+` had no business being there: just a type while formatting I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Sublime syntax highlighting that well, but assuming that it uses modern JavaScript you might be able to use an expression like this:

```js
/(?<=^--+.*?)\s*(?<!\[.)\b\w+\s*/g
```

This searches for words that occur on a line that begins with `--+` and are not preceded by `[*` (where * is any one character)

When run in a JavaScript regex engine, it produces the following:

```js
Array.from(
  "--+Move|Go [$Num] spaces [&Direction]".matchAll(
    /(?<=^--+.*?)\s*(?<!\[.)\b\w+\s*/g
  )
)
// [["Move"],["Go "],[" spaces "]]
```

Comment: Update: Added capture of spaces, as originally requested.

Comment: This almost works, but I must admit that is due to me missing some things in my post. Namely, variables can have functions separated by a '.' and it also doesn't get punctuation. So you got me exactly what I asked for, for which bravo!